# Find average for every 3 columns or data with NAs in r

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, multiple-columns, sapply

I want to calculate the means for every 8th column using data available below.
The data has 6 columns which contain information followed by data columns. I have looked for other codes available on this platform e.g 'How to average every 3 columns with NA in R'  but they dont have NAs nor do they have more than one information columns before data columns.

````
"I", "J"), DOB = c("25/11/2020", "29/4/2021", "29/1/2021", "24/10/2020", 
"24/10/2020", "10/2/2021", "16/10/2020", "16/10/2020", "28/3/2021", 
"8/6/2020"), DOG = c("3/5/2021", "28/11/2021", "27/8/2021", "17/5/2021", 
"19/6/2021", "25/9/2021", "5/5/2021", "12/3/2021", "22/9/2021", 
"8/12/2020"), REL = c(159L, 213L, 210L, 205L, 238L, 227L, 201L, 
147L, 178L, 183L), GRP = c("tyn", "tyn", "tyn", "ged", "ged", 
"ged", "buun", "buun", "bunn", "buun"), DOS = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, "30.5.2021", NA, NA, "25.3.2021"), M1 = c(42L, 0L, 38L, 
0L, 0L, 46L, 34L, 44L, 39L, 35L), M2 = c(0L, 45L, 42L, 34L, 39L, 
0L, 50L, 42L, 0L, NA), M3 = c(34L, 50L, 53L, 0L, 45L, 42L, 53L, 
0L, 45L, NA), M4 = c(42L, 0L, 34L, 34L, 50L, 53L, 0L, 34L, 50L, 
NA), M5 = c(0L, 45L, 50L, 42L, 0L, 34L, 34L, 42L, 0L, NA), M6 = c(38L, 
42L, 53L, 0L, 45L, 50L, NA, 0L, 45L, NA), M7 = c(0L, 34L, 0L, 
34L, 50L, 53L, NA, 34L, 50L, NA), M8 = c(0L, 39L, 0L, 42L, 0L, 
34L, NA, 34L, 42L, NA), M9 = c(NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 45L, 50L, NA, 
50L, 0L, NA), M10 = c(NA, 27L, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L, NA, 53L, 34L, 
NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))```

The problem is brought by the presents of NAs and columns which contain information before the data columns.
````

Comment: Can you update the piece of code? Right now it starts with "I", "J")

Comment: I have entered my code starting with ``` and ending with ```. The problem is that the first line of the code does not show up, bit the second line downwards. Am I missing something? This is the missing part: structure(list(ID = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H",

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
library(dplyr)
df[,seq_len(ncol(df)) %% 8 == 0] %>% apply(MARGIN = 2, FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Where `df` is a data frame

**TEST CASE:**

```
d2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:100, ncol = 20))

d2[,1:6] <- stringi::stri_rand_strings(n = 1, length = 4)

d2[4,16] <- NA
d2[3,8] <- NA

df <- d2
df[,seq_len(ncol(df)) %% 8 == 0] %>% apply(MARGIN = 2, FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE)

#> V8   V16 
#> 38.00 77.75
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me unfortunately . Also, I think the code should cater for the first 6 information columns. It gives me this error message:Error in seq_len(ncol(data)) : 
  argument must be coercible to non-negative integer
In addition: Warning message:
In seq_len(ncol(data)) : first element used of 'length.out' argument

Comment: if every 8th col in your data frame has numbers (also some NAs) then the above code should work (see the updated answer above) The best would be to update your question by sharing a toy dataset that resembles the original scenario.

Comment: Thanks but I would like means for all the 5 row0w for every 8th column, I am seeing 2 rows here.

Comment: What do you mean? it takes mean of all elements (ignoring the NAs) in every 8th column. it seems what you want is not clearly explained in your question.

Comment: Sorry I might have failed to explain myself but the data from your answer has 5 rows but the output shows means for one row only instead of all the 5 rows.